# Enterprise Application Integration: Ways to communicate show rooms with central office

Tags: java, mysql, jms, jakarta-mail, eai

I have a JAVA application installed in a customer which has many show rooms located all over the city and I need to implement a robust way to communicate them with central office.
The idea is to send sale orders stored in a MySQL db from these show rooms to the manufacturing department so the application can process them.
The problem is that internet connection is very unreliable and sometimes is no accessible for a few days.
Since there is no server in any show room (only client pc's) and no public IP in the central office, we thought sending an email with the sale order attached as an xml could be a possible solution .
Is this a good solution or should we use JMS instead? Is there any other way to do this besides JAVA Mail and JMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is inherently store-and-forward so it works well with intermittent connectivity, but you'll need to be able to store the messages on the client PC to be forwarded later.  The simplest way to do that is with an off-the-shelf SMTP mail server on the client PC, although you could certainly write your own software to perform a similar function.